# Split an array into sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to split an array:

```
$o = json_decode('[{"id":"1","color":"green"},{"id":"2","color":"green"},{"id":"3","color":"yellow"},{"id":"4","color":"green"}]');
```

based on the color attribute of each item, and fill corresponding sub arrays

```
$a = array("green", "yellow", "blue");

function isGreen($var){
    return($var->color == "green");
}

$greens = array_filter($o, "isGreen");
$yellows = array_filter($o, "isYellow");
// and all possible categories in $a..
```

my `$a` has a length > 20, and could increase more, so I need a general way instead of writing functions by hand

There doesn't seem to exist a function array_split to generate all filtered arrays
or else I need a sort of lambda function maybe

Comment: So, you want a function for every value in `$a`?  Or am I not understanding?

Comment: Err... Sorry, what's wrong with a loop? Generating anonymous functions seems like a massive over-complication here...

Comment: wouldn't one isColour() ... function be alot smarter?

Comment: Do you want to get all items which colour is green?

Comment: @Dagon indeed, it seems the answers do that

Comment: yup, even if they all spell *colour* wrong ;-)

Comment: @Dagon I see what you did there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$o = json_decode('[{"id":"1","color":"green"},{"id":"2","color":"green"},{"id":"3","color":"yellow"},{"id":"4","color":"green"}]');

$greens = array_filter($o, function($item) {
    if ($item->color == 'green') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Or if you want to create something really generic you could do something like the following:

```
function filterArray($array, $type, $value)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $item) {
        if ($item->{$type} == $value) {
            $result[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$o = json_decode('[{"id":"1","color":"green"},{"id":"2","color":"green"},{"id":"3","color":"yellow"},{"id":"4","color":"green"}]');
$greens = filterArray($o, 'color', 'green');
$yellows = filterArray($o, 'color', 'yellow');
```

In my second example you could just pass the array and tell the function what to filter (e.g. color or some other future property) on based on what value.

*Note that I have not done any error checking whether properties really exist*

Answer (score 1):

I would not go down the road of creating a ton of functions, manually or dynamically.

Here's my idea, and the design could be modified so filters are chainable:

```
<?php
class ItemsFilter
{
    protected $items = array();

    public function __construct($items) {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function byColor($color)
    {
        $items = array();

        foreach ($this->items as $item) {
            // I don't like this: I would prefer each item was an object and had getColor()
            if (empty($item->color) || $item->color != $color)
                continue;

            $items[] = $item;
        }

        return $items;
    }
}

$items = json_decode('[{"id":"1","color":"green"},{"id":"2","color":"green"},{"id":"3","color":"yellow"},{"id":"4","color":"green"}]');
$filter = new ItemsFilter($items);
$greens = $filter->byColor('green');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($greens);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Why would creating new classes be better than creating "a ton" of functions?

Comment: Functions are indeed in the global namespace. Nothing wrong with that statement :)

Comment: Classes are also in the global namespace. The only difference seems to be the amount of complication to complete a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more arguments you could use this function:

```
function splitArray($array, $params) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $item) {

        $status = true;

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if ($item[$key] != $value) {
                $status = false;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if ($status == true) {
            $result[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$greensAndID1 = splitArray($o, array('color' => 'green', 'id' => 1));
```